# Programmatically change timezone from an user SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, user-profile

I am trying to update the timezone value from users in SharePoint 2013. Unfortunately I cant see the changes in the mysite page. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void updateUserTimeZone(){
foreach(SPWebApplication wa in SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications)
{
foreach (SPSite site in wa.Sites)
                    {
                        foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                        {
                            foreach (SPUser user in web.AllUsers)
                            {
                                if (user.Name.Equals("Username"))
                                {   
                                    SPListItem item = web.SiteUserInfoList.Items.GetItemById(user.ID);

                                ushort zone = 0;
                                ushort.TryParse(getTimeZoneTextField.Text, out zone);

                                try {
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                    item["TimeZone"] = zone;                                       
                                    item.Update();
                                    web.Update();
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                { e.GetBaseException(); }
}
}}}}}
```

I hope the code is readable.

I get an output like this when checking after the updated value from item["TimeZone"]: username timezone 12 for example. But I cant see this value in the user profile Regional Settings Time Zone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you change the Timezone on their User Profile rather than the UIL? Generally it's a bad idea to mess with the UIL as it pulls it's info from the UPS profile.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am trying to do for all users. I get the users with the username and the properties List for each of them. I set the ushort value for the desired timezone and update the item["TimeZone"] with that value. I thought I would update the value under the user profile Language and Region / Time Zone with this. But I get no change there. The Region Choose your settings is also set to "Always use my personal settings". Still no change. The Value in the Properties List for the user is changed though.